# Merge shapefiles in QGIS 3.0.0 desktop

Tags: qgis-3

I have 3 shapefiles(shp) having containing the same attribute names. How do I merge these 3 shp files into one shp file in QGIS 3.0.0 desktop. I don't have the option of Merge Shapefiles to One under Data Management tools. Can someone help me?

Comment: Don't you have Vector-Data Management Tools-Merge Vector Layers?

Comment: @user30184 No "Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Vector Layers" in QGIS 3.0.1 and QGIS 3.1.0.

Comment: @user30184 "Vector > Data Management Tools > Merge Vector Layers" not available in QGIS 3.0.0

Comment: Ok. I have it in my 3.0.1 that is installed with OSGeo4W.

Answer (score 4):

You can merge vector files by "Merge vector layers" tool under "Processing Toolbox (Ctrl+Alt+T) > Vector general" in QGIS 3.

[image]

[image]

You can use this tool by selecting files without adding shapefiles into QGIS

[image]